# Error: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found

Tags: node.js, node-libcurl

I am developing a nodejs code and I am using the node-libcurl library to obtain the response time of a web page, but when I want to run the code on a linux machine I get the following error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^Error: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /tmp/checkURL/pingURL/node_modules/node-libcurl/lib/binding/node_libcurl.node)
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/checkURL/pingURL/node_modules/node-libcurl/dist/Easy.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

I wanted to ask before taking any action since it is a productive machine

Comment: When you run the code on another machine, remember to explicitly run `npm rebuild` as part of your npm install pass.